# Spring Boot Rolebased Access and Anonymous Access when having context path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I have two urls,

But these rules are not working.

```
/r is spring.jersey.application-path

1.http://localhost:6080/r/helloauthrozied/1234
    Expected:I want to permit only users with ABCD roles
    Actual: Users with out these roles can also access
2.http://localhost:6080/r/hellonoauthrozied/1234
    Expected:Permit anonymous access. No Authentication is required
    Actual:Expecting Authnetication
```

Can some one help me.

I made spring boot config like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ApiUserDetailsService userDetails;

  @Bean
  public ShaPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ReflectionSaltSource salt = new ReflectionSaltSource();
    salt.setUserPropertyToUse("username");
    DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    dao.setUserDetailsService(userDetails);
    dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    dao.setSaltSource(salt);
    auth.authenticationProvider(dao);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/hellonoauthrozied/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/helloauthrozied/**").hasAnyRole("ABCD")
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic();
  }


}
```

Comment: Is the `r/` in `http://localhost:6080/r/` the root context or an additional URL part from your controllers?

Comment: @kagmole It is root context of application

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `requestMatchers()` clause like this:

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/hellonoauthrozied/**", "/helloauthrozied/**")
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/hellonoauthrozied/**")
        .permitAll() // or .anonymous() if you only want non-connected users
    .antMatchers("/helloauthrozied/**")
        .hasAnyRole("ABCD")
    .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic();
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you post whole code. How to allow anonymous.

Comment: This is not working. ALL requests are being considered as anonymous